# Does laravel safe hashes user passwords?

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm running one project created with Laravel 5.1 and one guy said to me that passwords are not secure something like hashes don't used etc. But I can clearly see in this function that passwords are bcrypted:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

    ]);
}
```

And passwords also stored in DB as bcrypted. Should I be worried about his words?

Comment: use `password_hash` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: If you are not using Laravel's inbuilt Authentication, use Laravel's Hash class. `Hash::make('$data['password']')`. But in this case, it looks solid and you don't have to worry about hashing again.

Comment: `The Laravel Hash facade provides secure Bcrypt hashing for storing user passwords. If you are using the AuthController controller that is included with your Laravel application, it will be take care of verifying the Bcrypt password against the un-hashed version provided by the user.

Likewise, the user Registrar service that ships with Laravel makes the proper bcrypt function call to hash stored passwords.`

Comment: If "one guy" doesn't believe that is secure, then ask for a further detailed explanation of exactly why they consider it insecure, and what they would consider secure

Comment: that "one guy" probably thinks ROT13 and storing cleartext-passwords is secure ... a lot of people **think** they know something about cryptography - and only very few actually do ... because cryptography is a very complex and hard-to-understand topic.

Answer (score 1):

Default Laravel Auth requires passwords to be `bcrypt`ed, as you've shown in your code. `bcrypt` is an industry standard one-way password hash and is very good.

If you roll your own authentication, we can't control how you handle your password hashing. But default Laravel Auth is secure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm using this default that I've shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Laravel's inbuilt Authentication, use Laravel's Hash class. `Hash::make('$data['password']')`. But in your case, it looks solid and you don't have to worry about hashing again.

Comment: Also, the `bcrypt` function is just an alias accessing the `hash` binding in the container just like the `Hash` facade is. This resolves to an implementation of the `Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher` interface (`Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher` by default).

Answer (score 0):

You can read https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation#configuration about the Application Key.
Because of bcrypt , you can only decrypt a password where it was encrypted.

I am not saying that it is perfectly safe, but even if someone knows how **bcrypt** works, if they don't know the **encryption key**, they will have a hard time decrypting it.

So make sure to `php artisan key:generate` , if you are not using `.env` configuration file.